# Correct way to send json array to MVC4 controller action

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4, fancybox-2

I have a controller:

```
public virtual ActionResult CreateMultiple(int[] ids)
{
...
}
```

In JS, I get all selected checkbox, converting that into an array of int:

```
var params = [];
$("input:checkbox:checked.checkedPersons").each(function () { params.push($(this).val()); });
$("a.modalFormLink").attr("data-params", JSON.stringify( { "ids": params }));
```

Then, once I click that link, what I do is show a Fancybox with a view... sending the values of `data-params` attribute vía queryString in Fancybox href:

```
...
options.params = JSON.parse($(this).attr("data-params"));
var query = $.toQueryString(options.params);
...
```

**QUESTION:** Well, this is somehow working, if I have only one checkbox checked. If I have more than one, the binder fails and the parameter is null.

The content of the data-params attribute is:

```
{"ids":["4","6"]}
```

When I have just one value (and works) the content is:

```
{"ids":["4"]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using ajax to make this call.

If so, try adding

```
traditional: true
```

to your options in the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
url : 'someurl.com',
traditional:true,
data : someData
});
```

Comment: The problem was more related in the way I was passing the parameters to the ajax... we were using querystring instead of the data parameter. QueryString worked fine with single values... but not for arrays. Thanks!